# JavaFX Scale and Translate Operation Results in Anomaly

Tags: javafx-2

I have a Pane (test_) as the center child of a border pane. The child fills its area and grows when the window is stretched as expected.

Now I scale test_. Normally it would be centered in its area, but I don't want that, so I translate it back to the upper-left corner of its area.

But now when I stretch the widow it pulls test_ away from the upper-left corner of its area. Can anyone explain why this happens? The sample below incorporates a slider that scale's test_.

Thank you.

```
package fxuicontrols;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ScaleTest
    extends Application
    implements ChangeListener<Number>
{
    private final Pane  test_    = new Pane();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        test_.setStyle( "-fx-background-color: blue;" );

        Text    text    = new Text( "Upper left corner" );
        text.setFill( Color.WHITE );
        text.relocate( 0, 0 );
        test_.getChildren().add( text  );

        final Slider    scaler  = new Slider( .25, 1, 1 );
        scaler.valueProperty().addListener( this );
        test_.scaleXProperty().bind( scaler.valueProperty() );
        test_.scaleYProperty().bind( scaler.valueProperty() );

        BorderPane  root    = new BorderPane();
        root.setPrefSize( 250, 250 );
        root.setCenter( test_ );
        root.setBottom( scaler );

        stage.setScene( new Scene( root ) );
        stage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void
    changed( ObservableValue<? extends Number> oVal,
                Number oldNm,
                Number newNum
    )
    {
        double  scale   = newNum.doubleValue();
        Bounds  bounds  = test_.getLayoutBounds();
        double  width   = bounds.getWidth();
        double  height  = bounds.getHeight();
        test_.setTranslateX( (scale * width - width) / 2 );
        test_.setTranslateY( (scale * height - height) / 2 );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason your solution goes awry when the Scene is resized is because Panes are resizable nodes, so the layoutbounds of the Pane is changing as the Pane is being resized, but you aren't taking that into account in your translation calculations.

The following directly uses Scale and Translate transforms to avoid any resizing related issues.  Does this sample code do what you want?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.transform.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

// demonstrates scaling a test pane with content in it.
// slide the slider at the bottom of the scene around to shrink and grow the content.
public class ScaleTest extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(); }
  @Override public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    // create a test pane for scaling.
    Pane testPane = new Pane();
    // make the test pane background a different color if you want to see the extent of the pane.
    testPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");

    // create some text content to place in the test pane.
    Text text = new Text("Upper left corner");
    text.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 30px;");
    text.setFill(Color.WHITE);
    text.setTextOrigin(VPos.TOP);
    testPane.getChildren().add(text);
    Scale scaleTransform = new Scale();
    testPane.getTransforms().addAll(scaleTransform, new Translate(0, 0));

    // slider to scale the test pane.
    final Slider scaler = new Slider(.25, 3, 1);
    scaleTransform.xProperty().bind(scaler.valueProperty());
    scaleTransform.yProperty().bind(scaler.valueProperty());

    // stackpane added to pad out empty space when testPane is scaled small.
    // stackpane also clips the zoomed content when it gets larger than it's standard layout.
    final StackPane stack = new StackPane();
    stack.getChildren().addAll(testPane);
    StackPane.setAlignment(testPane, Pos.TOP_LEFT);
    stack.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");

    final Rectangle clip = new Rectangle();
    testPane.layoutBoundsProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Bounds>() {
      @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Bounds> observable, Bounds oldBounds, Bounds bounds) {
        clip.setWidth(bounds.getWidth());
        clip.setHeight(bounds.getHeight());
      }
    });
    stack.setClip(clip);

    // layout everything.
    VBox layout = new VBox();
    layout.setPrefSize(250, 250);
    layout.getChildren().setAll(stack, scaler);
    VBox.setVgrow(stack, Priority.ALWAYS);

    // show the stage.
    stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
    stage.show();
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know for sure (and I won't for a couple of days I'm afraid) but it certainly does look intriguing. Thank you.